# Cannot copy existing AZURE table data into new mobile service in Azure: ERROR 400

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have a database in azure and now I am creating a new mobile app that can access the data. SO I tried copying the tables following this tutorial:

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/05/24/using-an-existing-azure-sql-table-with-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx
```

I can see only the table name and valid number for records, and when I click on the table, it throws me an error saying that data was not loaded: ERROR 400.

Here was the query I used to resolve as given in tutorial but it gives me syntax error.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT sport_ody.EVENT_DETAILS ON 
GO 
INSERT INTO sport-ody.NEW_EVENT_DETAILS (eventId, locationId, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventDescription, displayFlg, lastModDate, soldoutFlg, eventName)
SELECT eventId, locationId, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventDescription, displayFlg, lastModDate, soldoutFlg, eventName FROM sport-ody.EVENT_DETAILS
```

Please guide. I cannot find much tutorials on it.

Comment: Please reply people.. Is it some really stupid question? I apologize but its my first time with azure and I am stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake on your schema name. 
On the beginning, you wrote sport_ody (with "_")
and in your query you wrote sport-ody (with "-")

Change this to correct the syntax error.

The Azure Mobile service use the Service Name to create a SQL Schema but it will change the hyphen by an underscore. So my-mobile-service.azure-mobile.net will create a schema with name my_mobile_service.

HTH

Jérémie Devillard